# Несколько таблиц, как сделать одну модель?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Суть: имеется несколько таблиц (поля частично совпадают)
channels, films, serials, с соответствующими моделями, нужно получить сразу все записи из этих таблиц, которые соответствуют некоторому условию.

Решение с join`ами не очень подходит.
С полиморфной связью не понимаю как достать несколько значений именно serials\films\channels, а не  all_content.

```
class AllContent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content, polymorphic: true
end

class Serial < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :all_contents, as: :content
end
```

С одним значением понятно

```
AllContent.first.content
```

Какие есть решения подобной задачи?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать прикрутить механизм [Single table inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)